# Is the Apache Directory directive supposed to be relative to the DocumentRoot or not?

Tags: apache-2.2, directory

Is the Apache `Directory` directive supposed to be relative to the DocumentRoot or not? I ask in the context of a VirtualHost, but it shouldn't make any difference.

In other words, is it supposed to be:

```
<VirtualHost>
    DocumentRoot /var/www
    <Directory /var/www>
    ...
```

or

```
<VirtualHost>
    DocumentRoot /var/www
    <Directory />
    ...
```

Both work. The [Apache *Directory* docs](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/core.html#directory) say:

> Directory-path is either the full path to a directory, or a wild-card string...

... but then they show two examples contradicting the "full path" statement.

**ED:** There are also contradictory examples on the [Apache Performance Tuning page](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/misc/perf-tuning.html#runtime) in the *FollowSymLinks and SymLinksIfOwnerMatch* and *AllowOverride* sections.

For fun I looked at Debian's default vhost setup and found this:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    DocumentRoot /var/www
    <Directory />
        Options FollowSymLinks
        AllowOverride None
    </Directory>

    <Directory /var/www/>
        Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
        AllowOverride None
        Order allow,deny
        allow from all
    </Directory>
    ...
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The documentation is correct, and the `<Directory>` directive should be the *full* path.

Your first example is how you should configure the directive for VirtualHosts, and applies the options within the directive to just the `DocumentRoot`. Your second example is referring to the filesystem root (literally `/`).

You haven't posted the rest of the directive, but this is typically used as a way of attempting to jail Apache and restrict its access, and is usually (but not always) placed inside the main `apache2.conf` or `httpd.conf` configuration files, with your VirtualHosts explicitly allowing access for their own `DocumentRoot` directories, so the two are often used together.

From the [Apache documentation](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/core.html#directory):

> Note that the default access for <Directory /> is to permit all access. This means that Apache httpd will serve any file mapped from an URL. It is recommended that you change this with a block such as:
>
> ```
>     <Directory />
>       Require all denied
>     </Directory>
> ```
>
> and then override this for directories you want accessible. See the [Security Tips](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/misc/security_tips.html#systemsettings) page for more details.

Comment: If the second example literally refers to the filesystem `/`, then why does Apache serve the `/var/www` directory?

Comment: Apache will serve the `DocumentRoot`. The `Directory` directive is totally separate, and has the effect of saying "apply the enclosed configuration to this directory and all subdirectories". More specific configurations take priority, so `<Directory /var/www/>` will override `<Directory />`.

Comment: I see. So `<Directory />` from a VirtualHost context can override server-wide Options (or other settings) of `<Directory />`? That makes sense. Thanks for the help.